# Difference between $activeRecord->load() and $activeRecord->attributes() for massive assignment in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

In PHP **Yii2 Framework**, what is the difference between

```
$activeRecord->load()
```

and

```
$activeRecord->attributes()
```

for massive assignment?

Comment: After some research turns out the load method uses attributes property (setAttributes) for massive assignment. The difference is that load() returns a boolean telling if it's loaded

Answer (score 1):

In simple words:

`attributes()` will give you list of all public non static attributes of the class

whereas

`load()` is used to populate the model with the data from end user

For more details check the following [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html)